# Lambda closure cannot be converted to std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Why does the second call to `f()` result in a compilation-error:

> lambda closure cannot be converted into std::function<int(int)>

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

void f(std::function<int(int)>f1, int x) {
    f1(x);
}

int g(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << x + y;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    f([](int x, int y = 10){ std::cout << x + y; return x; }, 20); // this works
    f([](int x, int y = 10){ g(x,y); }, 20); // this doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to remember if you need to use a specific C++ keyword in order to ***return*** a value from a function? What value do your closures return, and what is their type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you forgot a `return`:

```
f([](int x, int y = 10) { return g(x,y); }, 20);
```

Without `return`, your lambda doesn’t return a value, and C++ infers a `void` return type.